# undefined reference to 'd1mach_'

Tags: c++, c, fortran, gfortran

I'm trying to link a fortran subroutine with c++, but can't quite figure out what exactly is wrong here:
The fortran subroutine calls some functions eg. d1mach or xermsg, which aren't defined in the fortran subroutine but called externally. When compiling, the error is "undefined reference to d1mach_"(or xermsg). 
I tried linking a library I think might contain the said functions (There seems to be a file called d1mach.o and xermsg.o inside the library) but the same error still persists. What might I be doing wrong?

```
extern"C" {
void drc3jm_(double *L1,double *L2,double *L3,double *M1,double *M2MIN,
    double *M2MAX,double *THRCOF,int *NDIM,int *IER);
}
```

This is the function I use to call the subroutine, and haven't used any new headers beside iostream

```
*DECK DRC3JM
      SUBROUTINE DRC3JM (L1, L2, L3, M1, M2MIN, M2MAX, THRCOF, NDIM,
     +   IER)
CALL XERMSG('SLATEC','DRC3JM','L1-ABS(M1) less than zero or '//
     +      'L1+ABS(M1) not integer.',IER,1)
```

This is the declaration of the fortran subroutine which calls the undeclared function xermsg.

I link the library using the -L/*path*/lib instruction but to no avail.
The subroutine is to calculate a mathematical function and is part of the slatec codes.

Please let me know what other information you might need.

Comment: You need to link with the Fortran run-time library.  Try adding -lgfortran to your link command

Comment: @antlersoft I've done that already, I made .o files for both files, then compiled them using the -lgfortran and -L instructions. That results in this error, with or without the -L instruction.

Comment: Can you share the full command lines you're using to compile and link?

Comment: @Smeeheey I used the following instructions : gfortran -c drc3jm.f g++ -c test.cpp g++ test drc3jm.o test.o -lgfortran -L/usr/3j6j9j

Comment: Have you tried UTFG? *"What and where are r1mach, d1mach, and i1mach?"* http://www.netlib.org/misc/faq.html#2.17  They come from BLAS. For `xermsg` again the first link from the web search.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I tried using -l/usr/Documents/3j6j9j.a (that's where the file lib3j6j9j.a is stored) but it says library isn't found. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Maybe read my comment?

Comment: @VladimirF yeah I'm working on it, downloaded the BLAC as you suggested, and trying to link it. Will post as soon as I have updates. Thanks!

Comment: @VladimirF So I downloaded the blas.3.6.0.tar.gz file from the link you suggested but it seems to be a collection of .f files, none of them having the name of d1mach or something similar. So, 1. How do I link these .f files with my current program, and 2. Will some of these have the d1mach function intrinsic to the file? 

I apologize for my unfamiliarity with fortran or linking files as I have no training in either. Thanks!

Comment: You should use pre-compiled BLAS for your ooerating system. Usually included in Linux distribution. After that you link with `-lblas`

Comment: @VladimirF I compiled the BLAS library using the make file, and got the last instruction as ranlib blas_LINUX.a. Can I use this? Maybe using the same -l command?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I don't quite follow. I've manually downloaded a library in the Documents folder by the name lib3j6j9j.a, how is a pathname different from the directory in which the library is stored?

Comment: @VladimirF No leads. Same error even after using either -lblas or the -l command :( "undefined reference to d1mach_"

Comment: @MarkPlotnick even that returns "cannot find library...", Do I need to install the downloaded library? if so, how do I go about it?

Comment: What happens if you try g++ test.o drc3jm.o /your/path/lib3j6j9j.a  (i.e., no -l or -L)? Also, does "nm /your/path/lib3j6j9j.a" give d1mach.o and xermsg.o etc?

Comment: If nothing works for some reason, we can modify drc3jm.f such that d1mach(2) is replaced by 1.0d300 and all xermsg() are commented out. Then we can compile drc3jm.f stand-alone and seems to give correct results. Also, to be combined with C or C++, [GSL for coupling coeff](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Coupling-Coefficients.html#Coupling-Coefficients) may be more straightforward to use...

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong about `-l` being able to take a pathname to an archive as an argument. I've removed my comments suggesting that. Just use the archive pathname, as @roygvib said, or possibly `-L /usr/Documents -l 3j6j9j`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Hi thanks, and actually I'm not sure either why things will not go well in OP's case (possibly lib3j6j9j.a doesn't include d1mach etc...?). I will write some workaround for compiling everything from scratch then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why the problem persists might be simply because your `lib3j6j9j.a` does not include necessary files (such as d1mach). Actually, we can compile necessary files rather directly, so I will summarize the procedure below:

1) Download `drc3jm.f` (which calculates 3j-symbols) and dependencies from the Netlib/Slatec page ([here](http://www.netlib.org/slatec/src/) or [here](http://www.netlib.org/cgi-bin/netlibfiles.pl?filename=/slatec/src/drc3jm.f)). Unpack the archive file to get Fortran files (*.f).

```
tar xvf netlibfiles.tgz
```

2) Remove `d1mach.f`, `i1mach.f`, and `r1mach.f` (if any). Instead, download their alternative versions from Netlib/blas (*):

```
rm -f i1mach.f r1mach.f d1mach.f
wget http://www.netlib.org/blas/i1mach.f 
wget http://www.netlib.org/blas/r1mach.f
wget http://www.netlib.org/blas/d1mach.f
```

3) Compile all *.f files

```
gfortran testf.f90 *.f
```

together with a main program testf.f90 (in free-format), e.g.,

```
program main
implicit none
integer, parameter :: N = 1000
double precision coef( N ), M2min, M2max, M2
integer ier
ier = 0 ; coef(:) = 0.0d0

call DRC3JM( 15.0d0, 30.0d0, 40.d0, 2.0d0,  M2min, M2max, coef, N, ier )
print *, "M2min, M2max, ier = ", M2min, M2max, ier

M2 = 2.0d0
print "(a, f20.15)", "coef = ", coef( nint(M2 - M2min+1) )  !! -0.019081579799192
end
```

Then running the executable gives the desired result.

---

3-a) We can also make these *.f as a library and link with C++ codes, e.g., as follows:

```
gfortran -c *.f
ar rv mylib.a *.o
g++ testc.cpp mylib.a -lgfortran
```

with a main program (testc.cpp)

```
#include <cstdio>
extern "C"
double drc3jm_ (double*, double*, double*, 
                double*, double*, double*, double*, int*, int*);

int main()
{
    double* coef;
    double L1, L2, L3, M1, M2min, M2max, M2;
    int ier, k, N = 1000;

    coef = new double [ N ];
    L1 = 15.0; L2 = 30.0; L3 = 40.0; M1 = 2.0;

    drc3jm_ ( &L1, &L2,    &L3,
              &M1, &M2min, &M2max, coef, &N, &ier );  
    printf( "M2min, M2max, ierr = %10.5f%10.5f%d\n", M2min, M2max, ier );

    M2 = 2.0;   
    k = (int)(M2 - M2min + 1.0e-3);
    printf( "coef = %20.15f\n", coef[ k ] );  // -0.019081579799192
    return 0;
}
```

We can see that the two programs give the same coefficient (-0.019081579799192) for

```
j1=15, j2=30, j3=40, m1=2, m2=2, m3=-4
```

You can also get the same result with an online tool, e.g., [here](http://www-stone.ch.cam.ac.uk/cgi-bin/wigner.cgi?symbol=3j&j1=15&j2=30&j3=40&m1=2&m2=2&m3=-4).

---

But depending on cases, it may be simpler to use other libraries. One approach is to use the corresponding GSL routines ([here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/3_002dj-Symbols.html)) as

```
#include <cstdio>
extern "C"
double gsl_sf_coupling_3j (int two_ja, int two_jb, int two_jc,
                           int two_ma, int two_mb, int two_mc);  
int main()
{
    double coef;
    coef = gsl_sf_coupling_3j( 30, 60, 80, 4, 4, -8 );  // -0.019081579799205
    // NOTE: all j's and m's need to be doubled.

    printf( "coef = %20.15f\n", coef );
    return 0;
}
```

Here you need to link necessary GSL libraries (e.g., `g++ test.cpp -lgsl` or `g++ test.cpp /usr/lib64/libgsl.so.0 /usr/lib64/libgslcblas.so.0` etc).

---

Yet another approach is to use a latest program [WIGXJPF](http://fy.chalmers.se/subatom/wigxjpf/) (the related paper is [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1504.08329)). I tried this a bit and it seems extremely easy to install (only one `make`) and use. For example, enter the `example/` directory and try `gcc -I../inc csimple.c ../lib/libwigxjpf.a`.
According to the above paper, this program may offer some accuracy and performance advantage.

---

(*) For more details, please see [the Netlib/FAQ page](http://www.netlib.org/misc/faq.html#2.17) (thanks to @VladimirF in the comment). We could utilize the original d1mach.f etc in Slatec, but we need to modify them so as to obtain correct machine-dependent constants. The above BLAS versions of d1mach.f etc handle this automatically, so they are more convenient.

Comment: Wow this was amazingly detailed! I'd almost given up hope. Thanks so much @roygvib! I haven't reached the 2nd step yet but it seems like it's a solution to the - nan values I'm getting. Will update in the morning regarding the progress.

Comment: This works perfectly! The second approach is exactly what I wanted (The one with c++ linking. Without downloading the alternative versions of the d1mach etc., the problem was that it gave me -nan as the result. Downloading the alternative versions seems to have fixed this.). Thanks for providing a very elaborate and idiot proof answer!

Comment: Actually, this was the first time that I used the BLAS version of d1mach.f etc, which turned out to be very useful. (Because I didn't know it, I needed to manually modify them to run some AMOS code, see this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34082554/how-to-call-fortran-routines-from-c/34094408#34094408)... so updated it.) As for NaN, I guess it is because the old version of d1mach.f gives 0.0 as a "huge" value (unless we uncomment necessary lines). Anyway good to know that there is an easy solution :) Cheers